# Getting Error Run-Time error 53-file not found even though file is there

Tags: vba

I am trying to execute bin file using vba, code is working properly in one laptop, but in other laptop code is showing run time error 53 - file not found. Any suggestion please.

```
    Sub SevenZip()
    
    ChDir ("C:\Users\Desktop\LOGS\Test")
    
    Zipping = Shell("7zipCTest.bat", vbNormalFocus)
    
    End Sub
```

Comment: `ChDir` is not so helpful in this case. Please try `Zipping = Shell("C:\Users\Desktop\LOGS\Test\7zipCTest.bat", vbNormalFocus)`. VBA evaluates only `"7zipCTest.bat"`, which is not a valid full name...

Comment: Please don’t include irrelevant tags on the question as the code is clearly VBA code not VBScript.

Comment: Unless there actually _is_ a user named _"Desktop"_, `C:\Users\Desktop` isn't a valid path. The Desktop folder is located in each individual user's folder in `C:\Users`, e.g. `C:\Users\YourWindowsUserName\Desktop`.

Comment: Not working, tried below code, when i run code, no error coder is displaying too.   
Sub SevenZip()
Zipping = Shell("D:\Reports\CAS_LOGS\7zipCAS.bat", vbNormalFocus)
End Sub